# C# Invoke button control on separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, controls, invoke

I have seen a lot of questions about how to edit controls on c# form from a different thread but none make much sense to me. I understand that you can not change any UI from another thread than it's main. To make this work you have to use invoke and from there safely edit the control?

I have a button that starts writing in a file and the moment you press the button the button itself gets disabled so you can not start multiple threads that do exactly the same. When the writing is done I want the button to be available again but I can not get it working on this other thread.

I have this as the Generate_Click event from the form.

```
private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Generate.Enabled = false;

    int x = 512;
    int y = 512;

    MBrot mbrot = new MBrot(x, y);

    PB_Update lb = new PB_Update(0, y, Generator_PB, Generate, mbrot, this);
    lb.Start();
}
```

And this is in PB_Update.cs the ThreadWork() function, when the while loop is done the writing to the file is done and so is the thread so its ended and given a messagebox with "finished" now as last the button needs to be enabled again.

```
public void ThreadWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (currValue_ >= maxValue_)
            break;

        ThreadTick();
    }

    mb_.StopBrot();
    t_.Interrupt();

    MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    Generate_.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Small comment, your while condition would make more sense if it was just `while (currValue_ < maxValue_)`

Comment: @RufusL Actually it wont work that way and I don't really understand why. That code is part of a Progress Bar and your way it wont "progress" but instantly stop, maybe because it cant access the curr and max value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For WinForms you can execute directly on the thread which the control was created on through the [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, you can use Control.Invoke as well but, Control.BeginInvoke is preferred for UI operations.

```
public void ThreadWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (currValue_ >= maxValue_)
            break;

        ThreadTick();
    }

    mb_.StopBrot();
    t_.Interrupt();

    MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    Generate_.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        Generate_.Enabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: It does not recognize the current part. `System.Windows.Forms.Application does not contain a definition for Current`

Comment: This did the trick! Now ehm. what actually does BeingInvoke and delegate here?

Comment: I will update the answer with more details but essentially beginInvoke asynchronously invokes on the thread which the control was created on the anonymous method that is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, get a reference to the form that hosts the generate_ button (let's call it `myform`).  Then, at the bottom of your ThreadWork:

```
myform.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    myform.SetGenerateEnabled();
}));
```

And then inside your form create that method that enables the button appropriately.  (I used a method rather than just updating the button directly so that you don't publicly expose the button.)

This executes the commands inside the `{ ... }` on myform's thread, which is a UI thread, because it is UI.  At least, that's what I understand.  This is how I do all of my UI updating from other threads.

Comment: How do i make the reference to the form? Send it as object to the class?

Comment: @user1859829 However you want.  Make it a public static variable, make it a private instance variable and pass it around everywhere, etc.  I'd need to see more of your code to tell you specifically.  Where is `ThreadWork` located?  Is that inside your form class?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of a way to kick off an async task that disables a button for 5 seconds and then enables it again. Meanwhile, the rest of the UI is functional.

Note that this `async` method exists in the same class as your `Generate_Click` event, and runs on the UI thread. This means that it can enable and disable the button. But the long running task executes on a separate thread, so it doesn't lock the UI.

Hopefully this sample provides you a base to modify for your own code:

```
private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisableButton(sender as Button, 5);
}

private async void DisableButton(Button sender, int secondsToDisable)
{
    sender.Enabled = false;

    // In your code, you would kick off your long-running process here as a task
    await Task.Run(()=>Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToDisable)));

    sender.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to use this. The button must be disabled while the thread that writes to the file is active. You are using a timer and thread.sleep here?

Comment: No timer, I'm just using Thread.Sleep to represent a long running task. You could call some other method instead. The key part is that the call to the other method is done in a Task, which won't block the UI thread.

Comment: What is the name of the long running method? I was having some trouble understanding your sample since a lot of code is missing.